# how to validate firebase otp from api using php/laravel backend

Tags: php, laravel, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have a flutter app that send opt using firebase . problem is that when I send OTP from flutter app there no way to store that OTP in backend database for confirming.

Comment: You don't need to store OTP in backend, Firebase handles it itself

Answer (score 1):

you can verify the otp from firebase directily by using below function

```
await _firebaseAuth!.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: "+91${widget.phoneNumber}",
    timeout: const Duration(seconds: 60),
    verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
    codeSent: codeSent,);


final PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationCompleted =
    (AuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
  Utility.showLoadingDialog();
      print("in phone verification");
  _firebaseAuth!.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential)
      .then((value) async {
    handleNavigation(value);

  }).catchError((error) {
    print("in error");
    print(error);
    Get.back();
    // showErrorMessage("Try again in sometime");
  });
};

final PhoneCodeSent codeSent =
    (String verificationId, int? resendToken) async {
      Timer(
          const Duration(seconds: 15),
              () {
                // setState(() {
                  otpSendTimeOut = true;
                // });
              });
  // Update the UI - wait for the user to enter the SMS code
  String smsCode = 'xxxx';
  setState(() {
    _verificationId = verificationId;
  });
  utils.Utility().showSuccessMessage("OTP sent successfully");

};
```

Comment: how to i confirm it through backend.

Comment: you dont need to confirm it firebase will do the confirmation wheather otp is right or not